# In amcharts, is there any way to show tooltips text according to condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tooltip, amcharts, amcharts4

I want to show tooltips text in the chart according to my condition.
If my text value is 0 then I want to hide text otherwise show the text of the tooltip.

```
Series.columns.template.tooltipText = `{valueY}s`;
```

It gives value according to `{valueY}`. but I want to it doesn't show when `{valueY}` is equal to 0(zero).

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) for the tooltip [disabled](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/#disabled_adapter) property:

```
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
// ...
series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}s";

series.tooltip.adapter.add("disabled", function(disabled, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.values.valueY.value === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return disabled;
});
```

Alternatively for `target.dataItem.values.valueY.value === 0` you can use `target.dataItem.dataContext.yourProperty === 0`.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ymyoap) is a code pen, which shows the result.

Comment: You can instead set an adapter for `tooltipText` itself and `return "";` when you want to disable it. A non-blank value for `tooltipText` or `tooltipHTML` is what triggers the tooltip to begin with, so you're basically just undoing that.